# How to reuse a cucumber feature

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumberjs

I have a cucumber feature called "A" located at "C:\cucumber tests"

Now I want to create another cucumber feature call "B".

The first part of the steps of feature "B" will be exactly the same as in feature "A". I don't want simply to copy all the steps in feature "A" to feature "B"

Is there anyway to call feature "A" in feature "B"?

I appreciate it.

Comment: With cucumber-jvm you can use glue option. Take a look to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12867492/cucumber-jvm-step-definition-java)

Answer (score 1):

ruby version:

I don't believe you can call an entire scenario, but you can call steps from a step using the steps method.

```
Given /^(.*) is logged in$/ do |name|
  steps %Q{
    Given the user #{name} exists
    Given I log in as #{name}
  }
end
```

This will at least allow you to reuse your stepdefs, but not your scenarios.
[For more information see Cucumber Docs](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Calling-Steps-from-Step-Definitions)

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to put the features in the same file, you can use the background to run the same steps for each.

```
Background: Login the user
  Given I have an admin account
  And we have a user named "john"
  And I am logged in

Scenario: Reset Password
  When I reset the users password
  Then the server sends an email to "john"

Scenario: Lock User
  When I lock the account for "john"
  Then "john" cannot log in
```